# How to download an image using a URL with a query string instead of image path?

Tags: c#, image, url, download, query-string

I'm doing a C# windows application, and need to know how to download a picture which has a link with a query string, for example `www.mywebsite.com/img.aspx?imgid=12345` (which automatically redirects to the appropriate image based on `imgid`). I need to then save the file to the disk somewhere. I don't need any big fancy download manager, just the cleanest way to get such an image from a redirecting URL.

Comment: Although already solved, I forgot to point out the fact that I have 0.2% experience with C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient ())
{
    Client.DownloadFile("http://www.mywebsite.com/img.aspx?imgid=12345", "12345.jpg");
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it did not work properly. It created a file, but the file was 1kb with nothing in it. Then, of course, when attempting to load this file into the PictureBox, it failed with "Parameter is not valid." I'm doing `WebClient Client = new WebClient();` and `Client.DownloadFile(txtURL.Text, "C:\\12345.jpg");`

Comment: is the url you're trying to load actually doing an HTTP redirect to the image file?  ie, after the image loads do you see a different url in your browser?

Comment: It doesn't change the link, no. In Firefox, it just prompts to save the jpeg file, and in IE, it shows the image, still the same link with the query string. The prompt to save the file does not tell me the full path of the picture, but does show me the image filename. Chrome says "Redirecting..." and then automatically saves the image and shows up in the bottom of Chrome. There are no cases where it shows a new URL to the image.

Comment: By the way this is a third-party website, not mine. They gave us product data with over 7,000 items, each with an image link like the one above. My goal is to automate downloading all 7,000 of those images.

Comment: I just opened the `12345.jpg` file it saved in notepad, and come to find that it actually saved the `aspx` page instead of the `jpg` image.

Comment: UPDATE: It turns out that some of those links work, others don't work. As mentioned in my prior comment, I found that it saved the aspx page instead of the image. Well the page showed an error message (which is specifically the same error page I saw when opening the link in browser) So i tried a link which I know works in a browser, and bam, it worked! So now I just have to figure out how to identify IF it saved an error page instead of an image file...

Comment: can you give me an example of one of the image urls that won't download?

Comment: No those ones don't even work in the browser, all is working fine now, thanks :D

Comment: I will however be asking a new question how to check a jpg image file to see if it is valid...

Comment: You could check to see if the url is valid (returns a HTTP 200) before trying to download the file.  You could also check if the returned data is abnormally small.

Answer (score 3):

Use the WebClient class and he DownloadFile method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx

It's perfectly acceptable to pass a querystring parameter in the URI of the method.

Comment: (Generally same as answer above, just not as descriptive)

Comment: @JerryDodge This answer was posted first, FYI. So really, the other answer is generally the same as *this* one, just more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

Your file will be at `bin/debug` folder, and give the extension in which your browser download the file. like

```
{
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
                client.DownloadFile("http://www.mywebsite.com/img.aspx?imgid=12345", "selectedfile.gif");
            }
        }
```